# Como obtener un objeto evaluando al padre e hijos, en una lista linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

hola a todos estoy teniendo problemas con un linq, que pasa es que tengo una entidad llamado mesa, que tiene la propiedad producto, y sus hijos modificadores, pero con base a esos criterio deseo obtener un objeto, que en caso de no coincidir deberia lanzarme ningun resultado.

```
  var lista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmod>();
                
                var mesaObjeto1 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
                mesaObjeto1.JMPM_ProductoID = 3;
                mesaObjeto1.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                {
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 105,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 20,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 119,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                };
    
                var mesaObjeto2 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
                mesaObjeto2.JMPM_ProductoID = 5;
                mesaObjeto2.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                {
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 105,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 108,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 114,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                };
    
                var mesaObjeto3 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
                mesaObjeto3.JMPM_ProductoID = 8;
                mesaObjeto3.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                {
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 101,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 102,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 111,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                };
    
                // electo
                var mesaObjeto4 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
                mesaObjeto4.JMPM_ProductoID = 5;
                mesaObjeto4.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                {
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 101,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 102,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                    new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                        JMPMD_ModificadorID = 110,
                        JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                    },
                };
    
                lista.Add(mesaObjeto1);
                lista.Add(mesaObjeto2);
                lista.Add(mesaObjeto3);
                lista.Add(mesaObjeto4);



// objeto a buscar
        var mesa = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
        mesa.JMPM_ProductoID = 5;
        mesa.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista  = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
                    {
                        new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                            JMPMD_ModificadorID = 101,
                            JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                        },
                        new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                            JMPMD_ModificadorID = 102,
                            JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                        },
                        new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                            JMPMD_ModificadorID = 110,
                            JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                        },
        };
```

el linq:

```
var datosL = lista.Where(x => x.JMPM_ProductoID == mesa.JMPM_ProductoID).ToList();
            var datos = datosL.Where(d => d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any(s => mesa.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any(x => x.JMPMD_ModificadorID == s.JMPMD_ModificadorID ) ) ).ToList();
```

y el resultado que me lanza, es del objeto, mesaObjeto4. que es correcto, pero si cambio el valor de modificador de un hijo uno que no existe, aun me sigue lanzando este mismo objeto, entonces el criterio de busqueda no se cumple correctamente. alguna idea?
gracias

```
 var mesaObjeto4 = new jmpm_mesaprodmod();
            mesaObjeto4.JMPM_ProductoID = 5;
            mesaObjeto4.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista = new List<jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle>()
            {
                new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                    JMPMD_ModificadorID = 101,
                    JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio = 10
                },
                new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                    JMPMD_ModificadorID = 102,
                    JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                },
                new jmpm_mesaprodmoddetalle(){
                    JMPMD_ModificadorID = 110,
                    JMPMD_ModificadorPrecio =0
                },
            };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por cada elemento del arreglo `d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista` evaluar si todos cumplen la condición  de que `e.JMPMD_ModificadorID` está contenido en el arreglo `JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista` de mesa.

```
var datos = datosL
.Where(d => d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista
        .All(e => mesa.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista
                .Exists(mp => mp.JMPMD_ModificadorID == e.JMPMD_ModificadorID)))
.ToList();
```

Comment: var datos = datosL.Where(d => 
            d.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista.Any(s => mesa.JMPMD_MesaProdmodDetalleLista
                .All(x => x.JMPMD_ModificadorID == s.JMPMD_ModificadorID) ) ).ToList(); el resultado me lanza una lista vacia, si un modificador no coincide con los modificadores de la mesa mesa, pero si cambio para obtener una que existe me sigue lanzando una lista vacia

Comment: Cierto, ya la corregí.